# SQL Select Return Default Value If Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Database: **MS SQL 2008**

```
SELECT Listing.Title, Listing.MLS, Pictures.PictureTH, Pictures.Picture, Listing.ID 
FROM Listing INNER JOIN Pictures ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID
WHERE (Pictures.ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Pictures WHERE (ListingID = Listing.ID)))
```

The issue is, I have several "Listings" without a Picture, and because of this SQL script they don't show up. How can I get them to show up?

Maybe give the Pictures.Picture Column a value of "default.jpg" if the value is null? I'm pretty lost on this, so if someone could help, that'd be amazing. Sorry if I'm asking the question poorly as well, I dont understand how to ask really what I need it to do. But ask for more details and I'll post them.

Each Listing can have as many pictures as the user wants, I need this script to display a Listing even if it doesn't have a picture.

---

PHASE 2

---

Thank you all. So far I'm learning some new commands I never even knew existed. The issue now is its returning a row for each picture a listing has. But the default image is working great.

```
SELECT Listing.Title, Listing.MLS, coalesce(Pictures.PictureTH, '../default_th.jpg') as PictureTH, coalesce(Pictures.Picture, '../default.jpg') as Picture, Listing.ID FROM Listing LEFT
OUTER JOIN Pictures ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID
```

How can I get it so it only returns 1 row per ListingID ?

Comment: did you try the with the `WHERE` part of your original query ?

Comment: I have, and it doesn't work. I'll post the server info if people want to try some statements of their own? I'll create a new dummy database.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Two things:

1. Use `left outer join` instead of `inner join` to get all the listings, even with missing pictures.
2. Use `coalesce` to apply the default

   ```
   SELECT Listing.Title
       , Listing.MLS
       , Pictures.PictureTH
       , coalesce(Pictures.Picture, 'default.jpg') as Picture
       , Listing.ID  
   FROM Listing 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Pictures 
       ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID
   ```

**EDIT** To limit to one row:

```
SELECT Listing.Title
    , Listing.MLS
    , Pictures.PictureTH
    , coalesce(Pictures.Picture, 'default.jpg') as Picture
    , Listing.ID  
FROM Listing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pictures 
    ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID 
WHERE Pictures.ID is null
OR Pictures.ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) 
    FROM Pictures 
    WHERE (ListingID = Listing.ID)))
```

Comment: But how do I make it so it only returns 1 row per listing and not as many rows as there are pictures?

Comment: If there is more than one Picture but you only want one row returned, what are the rules for which Picture to use?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the where clause on your original query. Added that, with a test to include rows where there is no matching Picture.

Answer (score 12):

if you want to set the default value if the Pic is null you can do this via COALESCE key word:

```
SELECT Listing.Title, Listing.MLS, Pictures.PictureTH, 
COALESCE (Pictures.Picture, 'default.jpg') AS Pictures, Listing.ID 
FROM Listing LEFT JOIN Pictures 
ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID
WHERE (Pictures.ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) 
FROM Pictures WHERE (ListingID = Listing.ID)))
```

You can also achieve this via IsNull like below:

```
SELECT Listing.Title, Listing.MLS, Pictures.PictureTH, 
ISNULL(Pictures.Picture, 'default.jpg') AS Pictures, Listing.ID 
FROM Listing LEFT JOIN Pictures 
ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID
WHERE (Pictures.ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) 
FROM Pictures WHERE (ListingID = Listing.ID)))
```

you can read [here](http://codeasp.net/blogs/Vijjendra/microsoft-net/443/difference-between-coalesce-and-isnull) about IsNull and Coalesce

Answer (score 4):

Use `left outer join`  instead of `inner join`

`Inner join` will return results if and only if there is a result that satisfies the join.

`Left outer join` will return results from the *left* side table, and if the join is satisfied also add results from the *right* side table..

If you need to convert the null values returned from the *non-satisfying* joins, then use `coalesce` function like `coalesce(Pictures.Picture, 'default.jpg')`

Answer (score 2):

Need to do a LEFT join

```
SELECT Listing.Title, Listing.MLS, Pictures.PictureTH, Pictures.Picture, Listing.ID 
FROM Listing LEFT JOIN Pictures ON Listing.ID = Pictures.ListingID
```

Comment: Works, but returns a row for each picture as well. So It gives me 7 results because there are 6 pictures on listing 1 and listing 2 has no pictures, but is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Landmine, what database are you using?

If it's sql server 2005 or above or oracle, you can use the pivot command to achieve this.

Comment: MSSQL 2008, I'll post that info at the top too.